# IMAGE_CAPTURE on resultActivity the file doesn't exist yet

Tags: android, image, android-intent, camera, capture

This a rare case, i'm trying to capture an image from native camera activity on my samsung galaxy s3 and onActivityResult the file doesn't exist to read yet. If i disconnect the phone and connect again then the i can see the image on my explorer.

It likes that the camera activity writes the file with delay or something...

i have readed all questions and answers and other forums, but it is my problem; My code:

```
... onCreate
      File file = new File( _path );
      pathUri = Uri.fromFile( file );
...

  protected void startCameraActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pathUri);
        startActivityForResult( intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE );
    }    

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {   
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
        // test if exits image
        if((new File(_path)).exists())
            ... do something
        }
    ... continue
```

if((new File(_path)).exists()) always retunrs FALSE, how is it possible?

Thans in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen this occur in my app. However, this *could* potentially be a workaround.

**Note:** Declare the `Uri` instance `initialURI` globally so you can use it throughout the Activity. You could also change the name to something that suits your naming convention.

In this, right before the Intent is triggered, I pass a specific path for the Image to be stored at along with the name for the `File`.

```
Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

File cameraFolder;

if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals
        (android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "SOME_FOLDER_NAME/");
else
    cameraFolder= StatusUpdate.this.getCacheDir();
if(!cameraFolder.exists())
    cameraFolder.mkdirs();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "picture_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
        "SOME_FOLDER_NAME/" + imageFileName);
getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
initialURI = Uri.fromFile(photo);

startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

And finally, in the `onActivityResult()`:

**Note:** This I'm guessing should work. My application uses the Aviary SDK and the code for that differs vastly from the conventional work done in this method.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        // USE EITHER THIS
        imgView.setImageURI(initialURI);

        // OR USE THIS
        getContentResolver().notifyChange(initialURI, null);

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        try {   
            // SET THE IMAGE FROM THE CAMERA TO THE IMAGEVIEW
            Bitmap bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, initialURI);

            // SET THE IMAGE USING THE BITMAP
            imgvwSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

If you do not need the the Image stored on the SD-Card, you could delete it once you are done with it. This I am guessing (*guessing because I have never experienced what the OP is facing problem with*) this should do it for you.

Oh. Almost forgot. You will need to declare this permission in your Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Solved ! my problem was that i store the uri on my activity class, then when it returns from Camera capture Activity the URI_path was changed.

Comment: Thanks you, I had trouble because android told me from Media scanner that created file doesn't exist. While creating file I saved path like `mCurrentPath = file.getAbsolutePath()` and later on I get `myUri Uri.getUriFrom(mCurrentPath)`. It tourn out that created path was wrong - missing `//` . And right now I'm save only Uri and it works.